# How to request List<T> data or any other data from the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, controller, actionmethod

I need to render a DropDown list and I don't want to pass list's values to the View as a part of the model.

Basically what I'm trying to do looks like that:

```
@{
     var roles = Html.Action("GetRoles");
     var selectList = from r in roles select new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Selected = (r.Id == Model.DefaultRole.Id),
                         Text = r.RoleName,
                         Value = r.Id.ToString(),
                     };
  }
  @Html.DropDownList("roles", selectList)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DefaultRole)
```

And the action method

```
  public List<aspnet_Role> GetRoles()
  {
        return _dataContext.GetAspnetRoles();
  }
```

Of course that wouldn't work. How should I do that?

Comment: Heya Agzam - Its been a couple months : ) Why don't you want to add them to the model? the main idea here would be your ViewModel to do this. Best 'design' recommendations for MVC dictate using a ViewModel as the model here rather than a strict DB model for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the ViewBag. In your controller you can do this:

```
ViewBag.selectList = from r in roles select new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Selected = (r.Id == Model.DefaultRole.Id),
                     Text = r.RoleName,
                     Value = r.Id.ToString(),
                 };
```

Then in your View simply change your DropDownList to this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("roles", ViewBag.selectList)
```

ViewBag is a dynamically typed holder of "stuff", you can stick almost anything in there. :) It's meant to pass things to a view that aren't part of the model.